# Multiple ListViews, with same content, on different layouts

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, layout, android-activity

**Multiple ListViews, with same content, on different layouts**

So basically what I have is two ListViews that are getting their content from SQLite DB. I have created a BaseActivity below to extend my other activities to access the same data. The problem I ran into is that I cannot display the data because their are two different layout that contain these ListViews, one in a Dialog and the other in a TabWidget, that are both in separate activities.

So basically....

1. I need to know how to display two ListViews with the same data that are in different activities (one in dialogBox and the other in TabWidget)
2. The error I am currently getting is from the layout in the SimpleCursorAdapter is only for one of the ListViews and it wont add the other because it cannot find the View
3. I am not extending ListActivity at any point

Thank you very much in advance. I will be standing by to edit or clarify.

**Part of my Base Activity**

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity
{

    private SimpleCursorAdapter contactAdapter;
    public static final String ROW_ID = "row_id";
    private static ListView study_guide_list_view;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String[] from = new String[] { "name" };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.study_guide_item_in_listview };
        contactAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(BaseActivity.this, R.layout.study_guide_item_in_listview, null, from, to);

    }
}
```

**This segment is where I add the ListView to the TabWidget and it is currently working**

```
study_guide_list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

contactAdapter = getSimpleCursorAdapter();
study_guide_list_view.setAdapter( contactAdapter );
study_guide_list_view.setOnItemClickListener(listview_item_listener);
```

**Where I am trying to add the ListView in the Custom Dialog Box (does not work: error is on study_guide_dialog_list_view.setAdapter( contactAdapter ); )**

```
public OnClickListener save_slide_page_to_guide_btn_listener = new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        TabbedPagesActivity.getListViewAdapter();

        dialog = new Dialog(PDFViewerActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.study_guide_custom_dialog_box);
        dialog.setTitle("Select a Study Guide");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);

        study_guide_dialog_list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        contactAdapter = getSimpleCursorAdapter2();
        study_guide_dialog_list_view.setAdapter( contactAdapter );
        study_guide_dialog_list_view.setOnItemClickListener(listview_item_listener);

        Button dialog_ok_btn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_ok_btn);//it says cancel though
        dialog_ok_btn.setTextSize(20);
        dialog_ok_btn.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/AGENCYR.TTF"));
        dialog_ok_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow so I finally figured it out. The problem lies within the custom Dialog. Instead of calling...

```
study_guide_dialog_list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

it needs to be....

```
study_guide_dialog_list_view = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.list);
```

If you do not do this the findViewById will return null, hence the NullPointerException